# Drupal6: Removing template files

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-themes, drupal-templates

I have been using a custom template file called `user-profile.tpl.php` for a while. But wanted to explore the CCK Content Profile abilities.

I renamed the template file to something arbitrary, but instead of drupal defaulting to using the standard profile view it is complaining that it can't find the `user-profile.tpl.php` file.

So either it saves this in the database somewhere, cache is disabled so that is not the **Anyone know how drupal save the template file names? And how that can be reset?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you flush the theme registry whenever you make a change like that. You can do it using the link in the top left of admin_menu if you're using that module, or if not, go to Settings -> Performance and clear the cache.